# Opening a large file crashes my android application

Tags: java, android

I have a ionic capacitor and my app is deployed on android. In the app the use can generate PDF reports, which on the angular side seemed to crash the app for large files due to webview memory limitations.

So instead I decided to use the native android side utilising the Capacitor bridge like so:

```
@CapacitorPlugin(name = "Echo")
public class EchoPlugin extends Plugin {


  private final StringBuilder base64StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

  @PluginMethod()
  public void echo(PluginCall call) throws IOException {
    String base64Chunk = call.getString("value");

    if (base64Chunk != null) {
      String base64WithoutPrefix = base64Chunk.replaceFirst("data:application/pdf;base64,", "");

      if (base64WithoutPrefix.equals("LAST_CHUNK_SIGNAL")) {
        // This is the signal for the last chunk
        String completeBase64Data = base64StringBuilder.toString();
        base64StringBuilder.setLength(0); // Clear the StringBuilder for the next data

        // Now, `completeBase64Data` contains all chunks
        JSObject ret = new JSObject();
        File outputFile = new File(getContext().getFilesDir(), "output.pdf");

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
          fos.write(Base64.getDecoder().decode(completeBase64Data));
        }
        fos.close();

        ret.put("value", outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        openPdf(outputFile.getAbsolutePath());
        call.resolve(ret);
      } else {
        base64StringBuilder.append(base64WithoutPrefix);

        JSObject ret = new JSObject();
        ret.put("value", "Chunk processed.");
        call.resolve(ret);
      }
    } else {
      call.reject("Invalid chunk.");
    }
  }

  public void openPdf(String param) {

    try {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      File file = new File(param);
      Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getContext(), "com.gmail.myapp.myapp.fileprovider", file);

      intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
      intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/pdf");

      this.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
    }
  }
}
```

For smaller files this works perfectly. For larger files it also works without crashing, all until I try to open it in openPdf in which case the pdf will open but the app will crash with the following error in logcat:

```
[INFO:render_frame_host_impl.cc(11505)] RenderFrameHostImpl::MaybeGenerateCrashReport url = http://localhost/nav/reports, status = 0, exit_code = 0

[ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(156)] Renderer process (13517) crash detected (code -1).

[ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(112)] Render process (13517) kill (OOM or update) wasn't handed by all associated webviews, killing application.
```

Wondering if anyone can think of any solutions. If I don't try to open it then no issues. (Note these pdf files can be around 100mb in side in extreme scenarios) For the majority of my users its on the lower end

Thanks

Comment: Based on the error and your code, you are probably running out of memory, by trying to hold an entire base64-encoded large PDF in memory at once. Instead, try streaming the content: read some, convert that portion, write out that portion, and continue from there.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for the input. The only issue with splitting it bit by bit is the base 64 contains the formatting of the PDF as well. So trying to write it differently will result in corrupted formatting.

Comment: While base64 encoding has been obsolete for a very long time, it was designed to be decoded in chunks.